# Arel syntax for ( this AND this) OR ( this AND this)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

how would I do this in Arel  ( this AND this) OR ( this AND this)

Context is rails 3.0.7

Answer (score 7):

Mike's answer was basically what you're looking for

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.this_or_that(a1, a2, a3, a4)
    t = Model.arel_table
    q1 = t[:a].eq(a1).and(t[:b].eq(a2))
    q2 = t[:c].eq(a3).and(t[:d].eq(a4))
    where(q1.or(q2))
  end
end
```

some [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/flah00/activerecord-arel) I put together on Arel

Comment: I was able to get this to work (in v4.0.1) by using the t.grouping option. With your sample above, I was still getting (a and b or c and d). Your slides on page 12 had the grouping syntax that seems to work as expected ((a and b) or (c and d)).

Answer (score 2):

I'd put this all in a single where block. For example, here's a 'scope' based on a similar complex 'where' clause:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.my_complex_where(args)
    where("(col1 = ? AND col2 = ?) OR (col3 = ? AND col4 = ?)", 
          args[:val1], args[:val2], args[:val3], args[:val4])
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you could do it using this notation:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.my_complex_where(args)
    where("(col1 = :val1 AND col2 = :val2) OR (col3 = :val3 AND col4 = :val4)", 
          :val1 => args[:val1], 
          :val2 => args[:val2], 
          :val3 => args[:val3],
          :val4 => args[:val4])
  end
end
```

Comment: This isn't the best Arel solution because you still have to write SQL.

Comment: it's not even an arel solution

Answer (score 2):

You need to drop down to more raw AREL

```
t = Model.arel_table
a = (t[:a].eq(nil).and(t[:b].eq(nil)))
b = (t[:a].not_eq(nil).and(t[:b].not_eq(nil)))
Model.where(a.and(b))
```

Comment: this doesn't reflect the logic requested

Comment: Good catch, will upvote yours.  That's what I get for answering 2 similar questions at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the answers already given, you might also want to take a look at the gem '[squeel](http://erniemiller.org/projects/squeel/)'

Example:

```
Person.where{(name =~ 'Ernie%') & (salary < 50000) | (name =~ 'Joe%') & (salary > 100000)}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about helper methods, but you can [always drop down to (almost) pure SQL](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions):

```
Client.where("orders_count = ? AND locked = ?", params[:orders], false)
```